# Thinkpad Trackpoint Cursor Drift 16.04

Tags: thinkpad, cursor, trackpoint

I have a Thinkpad X260 with the touchpad disabled because I prefer to use the trackpoint. The problem I have, and this is driving me crazy, is the constantly drifting cursor. It's always moving towards the top right corner. I've tried suggestions such as creating a trackpoint.conf file in the /etc/tmpfiles.d/ that contains the line

```
w /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/drift_time - - - - 25
```

I've also tried creating a rule in the /etc/udev/rules.d as suggested in a few posts I've found through google, all to no avail. This problem does not exist in Windows 10 on the same machine. It is enough to make me primarily use Windows now. Has anyone figured out how to reliably resolve this issue?